# Level 2 combinations inside a category

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to query all possible combinations of 2 items inside a certain category, for example, my raw data is something like this:

```
Category A: 1, 2, 3  
Category B: Green, Red, Blue
```

And the expected result would be some like the below:

```
Category A: [1, 2]  
Category A: [1, 3]  
Category A: [2, 3]  
Category B: [Green, Red]  
Category B: [Green, Blue]  
Category B: [Red, Blue]
```

Is it possible at all?

As of right now, I was able to do a string split and tried to achieve the desired outcome by performing a cross join, but then SQL is doing the combinations of all different values, not taking into consideration the categories. After the string split, my data looks like this:

```
Category A: 1  
Category A: 2  
Category A: 3  
Category B: Green  
Category B: Red  
Category B: Blue
```

But when the cross join is applied, I have the combinations as follows:

```
Category A: [1, 2] (this is correct)  
Category A: [1, 3] (this is correct)  
Category A: [1, Green] (this is not correct)  
Category B: [Green, Red] (this is correct)  
Category B: [Green, Blue] (this is correct)  
Category B: [Red, 2] (this is not correct)
```

And so on...

And this is how I'm trying to do it:

```
    WITH z
         AS (SELECT category,
                    values
             FROM   table
                    CROSS apply String_split (Replace(Char(39), '')))
    SELECT z.[category],
           z.values                           AS value1,
           Z2.values                          AS value2,
           Concat (z.values, ', ', Z2.values) AS Combinations
    FROM   z
           CROSS JOIN z Z2
    WHERE  z.values < Z2.values
```

Inputs are appreciated!

Comment: `REPLACE` requires 3 arguments, `STRING_SPLIT` requires 2.

Comment: Please provide table definition and consumable data (an `INSERT` would be great). And post your actual query, not one with syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with a cross join like the following:

```
declare @t as table  (cat varchar(10),val varchar(100))

insert into @t 
values
('A','1')
,('A','2')
,('A','3')
,('B','red')
,('B','green')
,('B','blue')

select t1.cat, t1.val, t2.val
from @t t1
    cross join @t t2
where t1.cat=t2.cat
    and t1.val < t2.val
```

Result:

```
cat val val
A   1   2
A   1   3
A   2   3
B   blue    red
B   green   red
B   blue    green
```